# Tabulator : Clear Header Filter Field Focus after programatically setting a filter

Tags: tabulator

I have a nice Table running within a NetSuite Suitelet. When it is rendered, I predefine a Status filter.

```
tables.quotes.on("tableBuilt", function () {
    tables.quotes.setHeaderFilterValue(data.defaultFilterField, data.defaultFilterValue);
});
```

This does the job to preset the list to only show open quotes, while the dataset includes all types.

However, when the page has completed rendering, the filter dropdown list is showing until I click somewhere else on the page:

[image]

After the setHeaderFilter statement, how can I remove the focus from the header filter so the dropdown list is not displayed?